# If two polynomials in a single variable t, agree for all primes t, then they agree as polynomials

Tags: combinatorics, polynomials

I was reading Stanley's enumerative combinatorics V1 and in the 4th proof of proposition 1.3.7 (picture below), he says "if two polynomials in a single variable t (over the complex numbers, say) agree for all $t \in \mathbb{P}$, then they agree as polynomials. Thus it suffices to establish (1.28) for all $t\in \mathbb{P}$".

Why is this? It might be a well-known fact but I am not aware of it. I'll appreciate any response.

[image]

Comment: This is because the set of prime numbers is infinite, and two signle variable polynomials being equal on an infinite part of $\mathbb{R}$ (or $\mathbb{C}$) are equal.

Comment: So I could choose any infinite set (in particular any countably infinite set)?

Comment: Yes. To see this: suppose $P$ and $Q$ are two polynomials, and let $n = \max \{\deg P, \deg Q\}$. Then $P-Q$ is a polynomials of degree $\leqslant n$. If it has more than $n+1$ roots, it has to be the zero polynomials and $P-Q=0$, that is $P=Q$.

Comment: For what it's worth, $\mathbb{P}$ is the set of **p**ositive integers in Stanley's books, not the set of **p**rimes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All non-zero polynomials have only a finite number of zeros.

The difference between the given two polynomials is again a polynomial (of some unknown  degree.) Given hypothesis implies  that this difference polynomial takes value zero infinitely often (at the prime numbers). SO  the difference has to be constant polynomial zero.

Answer (score 4):

There is nothing special about primes: it is enough to verify they agree on infinitely many values. For example, a polynomial of degree 1 is determined by its values at 2 numbers. In general, a polynomial of degree $n$ is determined by its value at $(n+1) $ polynomials. This is the well known fact behind, and it is called "identity principle for polynomials".

Now suppose that two polynomials $p, q$ agrees on infinitely many numbers. There exist $N$ such that the two polynomials have at most degree $N$. Since they agree on $N+1$ values, they must be equal.

Comment: +1. Yes, But I thought the term "identity principle" was used for complex analytic functions. If we know a function to be a polynomial, and further know that its degree is $N$, then Lagrange Interpolation Theorem gives the formula determining it from its known values $(a_i, f(a_i)), i=1,2,\ldots N+1$.

Comment: It could be. Actually I think my answer is the less clear here, because I don't give the proof, but ok

Answer (score 2):

Call the polynomials $P(x), Q(x)$ and consider $P(x) - Q(x)$, which has every prime as a root. If $P - Q$ is not $0$, this contradicts the Fundamental Theorem of Algebra since there are infinitely many primes.